# What is the correct taxonomy of REST, HTTP and gRPC?

Tags: rest, http, networking, grpc

Do you think it makes sense to compare gRPC and REST or gRPC and HTTP? For both of those comparisons, I feel that I am comparing apples and oranges.

- HTTP is a protocol, it is used by both REST and gRPC (different versions though) so gRPC vs HTTP does not make a lot of sense.
- REST is an architectural style, and gRPC, afaik, is not.

So how to create a proper "taxonomy" of things?

Answer (score 1):

There are many comparisons of REST and gRPC ([list](https://www.google.com/search?q=grpc+rest))

A common third approach is [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/)

And, of course, there's really nothing new under the sun and, prior to these (modern) approaches, there was Web Services ([SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)), [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), [DCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model), etc. etc.

It's unclear to me whether you'd benefit from writing more on the subject as the existing analyses cover this ground.

The taxonomy (!) appears implicit in the definition you summarized: TCP/IP? HTTP? RPC? XML|JSON|YAML|binary etc. etc.

Relevance to a specific need seems the best starting point.